# add Code Style inside normal text flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

**I wonder if there is a way in flutter how to do this style to separate code from normal text**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`code_text_field`](https://pub.dev/packages/code_text_field) package.

Example:

```
class CodeEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CodeEditorState createState() => _CodeEditorState();
}

class _CodeEditorState extends State<CodeEditor> {
  CodeController? _codeController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final source = "void main() {\n    print(\"Hello, world!\");\n}";
    // Instantiate the CodeController
    _codeController = CodeController(
      text: source,
      language: dart,
      theme: monokaiSublimeTheme,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _codeController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CodeField(
      controller: _codeController!,
      textStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SourceCode'),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

For More customization use different options of `CodeController`

```
codeController = CodeController(
  text: source,
  patternMap: {
    r'".*"': TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
    r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(.*\)': TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
  },
  stringMap: {
    "void": TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
    "print": TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.blue),
  },
);
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Text.rich() then you can customize the text to any form you want, detail [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)